# How to download jaotc?

Tags: java, jaotc

Everyone is referring jaotc to http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/295. But from that web page, I cannot figure how to download jaotc.

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8255616. It was removed in Java 16.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is included in Oracle JDK version 9 ([Ubuntu installation](https://turreta.com/2017/07/03/install-java-9-in-ubuntu/))

If you have installed JDK 9, it is probably on your PATH or in **bin** directory of JDK's home.

Comment: I am using a Macbook Pro. It looks like there is only JDK 8 available.

Thanks a lot for the information.

Answer (score 2):

It is an experimental new feature in JDK 9 for Linux x64. So, if you are using Linux, just download JDK 9 from Oracle [website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase9-3934878.html) and in the folder $JAVA_HOME/bin you will find jaotc.

In the [link](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/295) that you shared, see:

> AOT initial release in JDK 9 is provided for experimental-only use and
>   is restricted to Linux x64 systems running 64-bit Java with either
>   Parallel or G1 GC...

Answer (score 0):

JAOTC is bundled with OpenJDK 9 and above but I'll recommend you using OpenJDK 12.